# Yii2. ActiveFrom. Add GET-param to URL without model array

Tags: php, yii2, active-form

I want simply to add GET-param to URL from user.
I use third party module action, so I don't want to change the signature that is

```
public function actionReset($id, $code)
```

I have such model in controller

```
$model = new DynamicModel([
    'code'
]);
$model->addRule(['code'], 'required');
$model->addRule(['code'], 'string');
```

And such `ActiveForm`

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'method' => 'get',
    'action' => [
        \yii\helpers\Url::current()
    ]
]) ?>

<?php echo $form->field($model, 'code')->textInput()->label(false); ?>

<?php echo Html::submitButton(Yii::t('user', 'Continue')); ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

And with such implementation it passes with an array wrapper:

[image]

Is it possible to avoid such wrapper without custom js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/8015)

Now my view code looks like

```
            <?=Html::beginForm(Url::current(), 'get', ['csrf' => false]);?>
            <?=Html::input('text', 'code', 'test')?>

            <?=Html::a('Submit', '', [
                'data' => [
                    'method' => 'get',
                ]
            ])?>
            <?=Html::endForm();?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Could be that you can specify this in activeForm configuration

```
       <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
          'method' => 'get',
          'action' => [
              \yii\helpers\Url::current(), 'your_att' => $your_value
          ]
      ]) ?>
```

or in array format

```
      <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
          'method' => 'get',
          'action' => [
              \yii\helpers\Url::current(), ['your_att' => $your_value],
          ]
      ]) ?>
```

Comment: yes, but I want to take an input from user. I found solution. I'll post it soon.